# Join and sum doubling results

Tags: sql, join, sum, left-join

I have two tables, t_tran_log and t_item_master.

When I run this query against t_tran_log, I get accurate results:

```
declare @startdate as datetime; declare @enddate as datetime
set @startdate = '9/13/20 5am'; set @enddate = dateadd(hour,24,@startdate)

select
cast(t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time  - '1900-01-01 05:00' as date) tran_date
,t.item_number
,sum(t.tran_qty) qty

from t_tran_log t

where t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time >= @startdate
and t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time < @enddate
and t.tran_type = '750'  and t.description like 'Customer Return' and t.hu_id not like '1Z%'

group by cast(t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time  - '1900-01-01 05:00' as date), t.item_number
```

But when I try to pull in additional item details from the other table via a left join, I suddenly get double the results for the item quantities! What am I doing wrong?

```
declare @startdate as datetime; declare @enddate as datetime
set @startdate = '9/13/20 5am'; set @enddate = dateadd(hour,24,@startdate)

select
cast(t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time  - '1900-01-01 05:00' as date) Date
,t.item_number
,i.dept_name
,i.class_name
,i.subclass_name
,sum(t.tran_qty) qty

from t_tran_log t

left join t_item_master i on t.item_number = i.item_number

where t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time >= @startdate
and t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time < @enddate
and t.tran_type = '750'  and t.description like 'Customer Return' and t.hu_id not like '1Z%'

group by cast(t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time  - '1900-01-01 05:00' as date), t.item_number, i.dept_name, i.class_name, i.subclass_name
```

Comment: Short answer: you do a many-to-many-join instead of 1-to-many, i.e. ´t_item_master.item_number` is not unique

Answer (score 0):

Likely, there are multiple rows in `item_master` that match the join conditions. As a result, rows are multiplied, and the aggregate functions goes wrong.

Consider pre-aggregating in a subquery first:

```
select t.*, i.dept_name, i.class_name, i.subclass_name
from (
    select
        cast(t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time  - '1900-01-01 05:00' as date) tran_date
        ,t.item_number
        ,sum(t.tran_qty) qty
    from t_tran_log t
    where 
        t.start_tran_date + t.start_tran_time >= @startdate
        and t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time < @enddate
        and t.tran_type = '750'  
        and t.description like 'Customer Return' 
        and t.hu_id not like '1Z%'
    group by 
        cast(t.start_tran_date+t.start_tran_time  - '1900-01-01 05:00' as date), 
        t.item_number
) t
left join t_item_master i on t.item_number = i.item_number
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not quite work. Now I get two rows of results for each item number?